# How EC2 user-data is treated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

### Question

It looks EC2 instance is configured to check if user-data is executable or simple ascii text by looking at the first line to switch behaviour.

Other than #! UNIX shebang like and #cloud-config, are there any other markers by which to tell EC2 how to treat user-data?

### Background

Trying to understand what is **user-data** and how it is treated. Initially thought it is a simple text file somewhere in the EBS root volume to store information about the EC2 instance.

[Working with Instance User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data) says that user data is ascii text (base64) and the example user data is pipe delimited key/value pairs.

```
replicate-every=1min | replicate-every=5min | replicate-every=10min
```

And saw that it is also a mechanism to run commands.

[Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) tells user data can be used to perform common automated configuration tasks either shell script or cloud-init directives.

```
#!/bin/bash
...

#cloud-config
...
```

Hence looking for a clear comprehensive definitions of what **user-data** is and how it is treated. I suppose "script or cloud config, or otherwise simple ascii text. It is determined by the leading characters of the first line". Is it correct?

---

### Update

Based on the comment by Mark.B, searched cloud-init in AWS documents.

[cloud-init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#amazon-linux-cloud-init)

> The cloud-init package is an open-source application built by Canonical that is used to bootstrap Linux images in a cloud computing environment, such as Amazon EC2. Amazon Linux contains a customized version of cloud-init. It enables you to specify actions that should happen to your instance at boot time.

Comment: What you are looking for is the documentation on the `cloud-init` service (which is not AWS specific) https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Do you want this for Linux or Windows?

Comment: Hello @JohnRotenstein, thanks for your response. it is for Linux.